# Проблема конвертирования из .py в .exe

Tags: python

Написал простой MP3 плеер на Python, используя Tkinter.
При запуске в PyCharm программа работает хорошо, музыка играет.

Далее поставил себе задачу сконвертировать эту программу в .exe. Через командную строку установил `auto-py-to-exe`, указал путь к файлу .py добавил все папки, которые нужны. Всё успешно конвертировалось и программа запускается, **НО** не играет сама музыка.

Как можно решить эту проблему? В коде проблема или что-то не так сконвертировал?

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame

from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title('Music Player')
root.iconbitmap("music.ico")
root.geometry('500x400')

# Initialize Pygame Mixer
pygame.mixer.init()


# Add Song Function
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='audio/', title='Choose a Song', filetypes=(("mp3 files", "*.mp3"),))
    song = song.replace("G:/MusicPlayer/audio/", "")
    song = song.replace(".mp3", "")
    song_box.insert(END, song)


# Add Many Songs Function
def add_many_songs():
    songs = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir='audio/', title='Choose a Song', filetypes=(("mp3 files", "*.mp3"),))

    for song in songs:
        song = song.replace("G:/MusicPlayer/audio/", "")
        song = song.replace(".mp3", "")
        song_box.insert(END, song)


# Play Function
def play_song():
    song = song_box.get(ACTIVE)
    song = f'G:/MusicPlayer/audio/{song}.mp3'

    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)


# Stop Function
def stop_song():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    song_box.selection_clear(ACTIVE)


# Global Variable Pause
global paused
paused = False


# Pause Function
def pause_song(is_paused):
    global paused
    paused = is_paused

    if paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        paused = False
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        paused = True


# Playlist
song_box = Listbox(root, bg='grey', fg='green', width=60, selectbackground='black')
song_box.pack(pady=20)

# Button Images
play_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='icon/play_icon.png')
pause_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='icon/pause_icon.png')
stop_btn_img = PhotoImage(file='icon/player_stop_1081.png')

# Create Player Control Frame
controls_frame = Frame(root)
controls_frame.pack()

# Button
play_btn = Button(controls_frame, image=play_btn_img, borderwidth=0, command=play_song)
pause_btn = Button(controls_frame, image=pause_btn_img, borderwidth=0, command=lambda: pause_song(paused))
stop_btn = Button(controls_frame, image=stop_btn_img, borderwidth=0, command=stop_song)

play_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
pause_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
stop_btn.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)

# Create Menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

# Add Song Menu
add_song_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label='Add Songs', menu=add_song_menu)
add_song_menu.add_command(label='Add One Song To Playlist', command=add_song)
# Add Many songs
add_song_menu.add_command(label='Add Many Songs To Playlist', command=add_many_songs)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: если без pycharm запускаешь py-файл он работает? до компиляции в "бинарник"?

Comment: @Yakov, без pycharm py-файл работает и до компиляции тоже